# How to update tikz-cd (TexLive)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My tikz-cd is out-of-date.

I have found this version which seems the latest:
http://pgf.sourceforge.net/

Then I unzip the package, put the "pgf" from the package to my ~/texmf directory.

But I don't know what to do to get my latex system to use the new version instead of the old version.

Any ideas?

Comment: [how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

Comment: I upgraded to TexLive 2015 and tikz-cd is still not working...

Comment: On another computer I have TexLive 2015 and tikz-cd is working, but I cannot re-produce it now... :(

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the solution:

First I need to upgrade to TexLive 2015, using the script that can be downloaded.

Then:

`sudo tlmgr install pgf`

`sudo tlmgr install tikz-cd`